# my program seems good on Windows,while on Ubuntu it is crashed

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm programing a plane game on Windows by QT which seems good,while on Ubuntu it is crashed.It has a `QLinkedList<Bullet *> Bullet_list`.and it is crashed after `Bullet_list.removeOne(*ite)`

I've tried judging every Null-pointer,adding `delete *ite` after `removeOne()`,but it doesn't work.

`Plane_Player *Plane_p;`

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(Refresh()));
void GameWindow::Refresh(){
QLinkedList<Bullet*>::iterator ite;
       for(ite = Plane_p->Bullet_list.begin();ite != Plane_p->Bullet_list.end();++ite)
       {
           (*ite)->Go();//move the bullets on the screen
           if((*ite)->isOutOfBound())
               Plane_p->Bullet_list.removeOne(*ite);//crashed after this.
       }
}

class Plane_Player
{
public:
    QLinkedList<Bullet *> Bullet_list;
}
```

in the function `Refresh()`,there is other `removeOne()`,and it's all crashed after it.

I hope it won't be crashed on Ubuntu.
the whole project:https://github.com/Vinolzy/QT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html) states that:

> If you want to insert, modify, or remove items in the middle of the
>   list, you must use an iterator.

So far so good. But I think the problem is that you reuse the iterator after removing an element from your linked list. To fix it you need to update your iterator after removal. For example, you can rewrite your loop like:

```
QLinkedList<Bullet*>::iterator ite = Plane_p->Bullet_list.begin();
while (ite != Plane_p->Bullet_list.end())
{
  (*ite)->Go();
  if ((*ite)->isOutOfBound())
  {
    ite = Plane_p->Bullet_list.erase(ite);
  }
  else
  {
    ++ite;
  }
}
```

And finally, it works differently on different platforms because your code leads to an undefined behavior.